# PHP file handling not able to display image file

Tags: php, file

I am trying to display an image file in `<img>` tag using PHP file handling functions but I'm getting following error instead of an actual image:

**image cannot be displayed because it contains errors**

Here's my code to read and display the image file:

```
<?php
header("content-type: image/jpeg");
$filename = "images/sunset.jpg";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$img= fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
?>

<img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="image" />
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I voted to reopen this, as the "duplicate question" isn't a duplicate. You are asking about serving up content type `image/jpeg`, not `text/html`.

Comment: Think about it: For a normal image, do you open the image file in an editor, and then copy & paste the _binary contents_ of that image file into the `src` attribute of an HTML `img` element? No? Because that’s effectively what your script is doing here.

Comment: Actually delboy's answer is pretty much correct. But do you really need to fopen an image in PHP? That just sounds a bit weird to me. Since what's the difference between accessing your PHP script and the file directly?

Answer (score 0):

You are simply sending the wrong stuff. You declare a content type of `image\jpeg`, then proceed to return HTML markup.

Get rid of the HTML and just `echo $img;`

Comment: It will output binary code of image. Must encode first.

Comment: Nope, because we declare the content type and the browser can handle that

Comment: You are talking about when using an HTML tag and need to declare encoding first before the raw data. Not needed in this case. Please undo your downvote.

Comment: This is what you are talking about Justinas. https://delboy1978uk.wordpress.com/2014/12/01/outputting-images-as-base64-encoded-strings/